# Can anyone recommend OCR software to process invoices?

Tags: ocr

guys. I need OCR software that can read a variety of types of invoices and extract data. The exported data should be presented in a tabular format, preferably with a link to the source document. It must be able to read the documents in a variety of formats (.pdf, .jpg, .gif, .tiff, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

You can visit Wikipedia, on which there is a list of OCR software vendors, professional OCR vendors such as ExperVision, Abby, Nuance... will be better choice. As I know, formats of invoices are complex and variable. It need design templates aimed at each kind of invoice. Therefore, standard OCR is not the best choice and it generally needs customizing development. So you’d better choose OCR vendors providing customized services.

Answer (score 1):

How many forms do you want to process per day ?
How many different types of invoices and layouts do you want to process ?
How many different paper sizes ?
How accurate do you need it to be ?
How many people will be using the system for data correction / validation ?
What system are you exporting the data to ?
How many fields do you want to extract automatically ?

Expect to pay for such solutions if you want it yo read any and every type of invoice.  These solutions listed below are not cheap as they are high end solutions.

- http://www.documation.co.uk/emc_captiva.html
- http://www.captaris-dt.com/product/dokustar-capturesuite/en/
- http://www.abbyy.com/data_capture_software/
- http://www.kofax.com/forms-processing/
- http://www.readsoft.com/

The cost will depend on how many invoices you want to process.  My best guess is that the Abbyy product will probably be the cheapest option.

If you have a limited number of documents types to read you may get away with a simpler OCR fixed-form solution as opposed to the free from solutions above.

Also, your scanning solution required will depend very much on your volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Lake makes one that integrates with sharepoint. It is also made to integrate with other kinds of systems.

http://www.knowledgelake.com/